# Issue changing CSS back to default using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, blazor

I can change other elements on the page using Jquery, but i can't seem to be able to toggle back to the default css class when it is using ::before..

### **Default Checkbox css in action**

[image]

### **Checkbox Checked css in action**

[image]

Now i have a button, that when its clicked, should reset my css to the default Checkbox - but it doesnt seem to work for me... The button stays green and it doesn't move to the left..

**

## After button clicked example

**
[image]

CSS -

```
<style>


            .checkbox {
                appearance: none;
                border: 2px solid #ccc;
                border-color: red;
                border-radius: 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
                height: 24px;
                outline: none;
                position: relative;
                transition: 0.3s;
                width: 37px;
            }

                .checkbox::before {
                    background: red;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    content: "";
                    height: 15px;
                    left: 0px;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 2px;
                    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
                    width: 15px;
                }

                .checkbox:checked::before {
                    background: green;
                    transform: translateX(18px);
                }

                .checkbox:checked {
                    border-color: green;
                }

            .float-container {
                border: 3px solid #fff;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .float-child {
                border: 2px solid red;
                padding: 20px;
                text-align-last: center;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .float-child-unknown {
                border: 2px solid red;
                padding: 20px;
                text-align-last: center;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
```

JS -

```
function outsideModalClick() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
            $('.float-child').css('border', '2px solid red');
            $('.iconShow').toggleClass('iconhide');
            $('.checkbox:checked::before').toggleClass('.checkbox::before');
            $('.checkbox:checked').toggleClass('.checkbox');
        }
    })
}
```

### Edit - Still not working - css is not being applied

[image]

Comment: You can't select pseudo-elements with JS as they are not in the DOM.

Comment: Use CSS classes to toggle

Comment: Please include your HTML as well. It seems you would want to "uncheck" the checkbox to reset it, not toggle the class "checkbox". Maybe you just need to `$('.checkbox').prop('checked', false);` instead of class toggling

Comment: also fyi, the call to "toggleClass" should not be a selector (i.e. ".checkbox"), it needs to be the class name (i.e "checkbox"). So it should be `$('.checkbox:checked').toggleClass('checkbox');` with no "."

Comment: @zgood brilliant your recommendation worked, using prop! i am still early in my career using jquery and css. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: To point out the obvious, using Blazor, you can write c# code to replace class names on events...